# Cannot handle an error inside a promise

Tags: javascript

I have this function that takes a path and fetches some information about it (using node.js capabilities)

### Code

```
import fs from 'fs'
import fse from 'fs-extra'
import { join } from 'path'


/**
 * Take in file path and return contents with stat
 * @param  {String} path
 * @return {Array}
 */
export default path => {
  return readdir(path).then(files => {
    const statsPromises = files.map((file, i) => {
      const p = join(path, file)
      return stat(p).then(stat =>
        ({
          // THIS ONE LINE BELOW THROWS UN-HANDLED ERRORS FOR SOME PATHS
          // Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir
          folderItemsCount: stat.isDirectory() ? fs.readdirSync(p).length : null,
          name: file,
          path: p,
          stat
        })
      , err => console.log("Path access error ", err))
    })
    return Promise.all(statsPromises)
  }).then(contents =>
    contents.filter(Boolean)
  )
}


// ============== HELPER FUNCTIONS ==============
/**
 * Get Array for path contents. Checks if path exists
 * @param  {String} path
 * @return {Promise}
 */
export function readdir (path) {
  return pathExists(path)
    ? fse.readdir(path)
    : Promise.reject(new Error('Path does not exist'))
}

/**
 * Alias of fse.existsSync
 * @param  {String} path
 * @return {Boolean}
 */
export function pathExists (path) {
  return fse.existsSync(path)
}

/**
 * Get path stat
 * @param  {String} path
 * @return {Promise}
 */
export function stat (path) {  
  return fse.stat(path)
}
```

### Problem

I don't know how to handle the error for the following line:

```
folderItemsCount: stat.isDirectory() ? fs.readdirSync(p).length : null
```

I want it to:

- **return a number** of items if it can access a folder (this does work when it checks accessible dirs)
- **return a string "unknown" (or null)** if it cannot access a folder instead of throwing an un-handled error: `Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir`

The line below handles `stat()` but not `scandir()`

```
, err => console.log("Path access error ", err))
```

Answer (score 2):

Without digging too much into your code, a promise either resolves or rejects, which your handlers either hit the 'then' or the 'catch'. I see you're using .then, but not .catch. Also keep in mind that Promise.all will reject if any promise in that list rejects, so you've got an all-or-nothing promise there.

Comment: I'm new to promises, not sure how to improve it. But it works fine if I'm not fetching `folderItemsCount:`. If it cannot access a path, it just logs the path that it couldn't access in `stat()` with this line: `, err => console.log("Path access error ", err))`. But I need to fetch ``folderItemsCount:`` and it's not getting handled by anything right now, hence `scandir()` throws an un-handled error for some paths

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding a `try/catch`

```
export default path => {
  return readdir(path).then(files => {
    const statsPromises = files.map((file, i) => {
      const p = join(path, file)
      return stat(p).then(stat =>
        let countResult 
        if (stat.isDirectory()) {
          try {
            countResult = fs.readdirSync(p).length
          }
          catch (error) {
            countResult = 'unknown'
          }
        } else { countResult = null }
        return ({
          folderItemsCount: countResult,
          name: file,
          path: p,
          stat
        })
      , err => console.log("Path access error ", err))
    })
    return Promise.all(statsPromises)
  }).then(contents =>
    contents.filter(Boolean)
  )
}
```